# Most efficient way to remove currency symbol and set to 2 decimal places

Tags: php

Is there a more efficient way to:

- Remove the £ symbol
- Set number to 2 decimal places

```
number_format((float)str_replace('£','',$number), 2, '.', '')
```

Comment: you can use  round(floatval($input));

Comment: Casting a monetary value to `float` can be pretty troublesome if accuracy is important in any way.

Comment: yea...to cover all the possible problems you can make a function, that will cover ,. and all unexpected issues

Comment: @Lajos Arpad , that method was tested a few hundred times. We work with different currencies and that method was made to transform to float no matter what currency and the format of the amount (1.400,50 $ or 1,400.50 $ + strings in front or after the value)

Answer (score 0):

Uh, like using [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) (remove the first character) instead of str_replace (searches the whole string)

```
number_format((float)substr($number, 1), 2, '.', '')
```

Or using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
sprintf('%0.2f', $number)
```

Which is faster (if it matters) will depend on your benchmark.

**Note that if you're dealing with a value normally larger than a regular decimal or float, none of these methods will really be able to help you with accurate precision. You will need to use something more complex to do the rounding yourself. i.e. divide from the last number up to the first with carries.